# Difference between HashMaps put and add

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

What is the difference between

```
ans.put(key, new ArrayList());
```

and

```
ans.get(key).add(s);
```

`ans` is the `HashMap` and `s` is a `String` object.

Comment: The first one is placing an empty list into the map, the second one is adding items to an existing list in the map.

Comment: `HashMap` itself has no `add` method. By using `get` you access the value associated to the given `key`. Which, in your case, is an `ArrayList`. The `add` method belongs to this `ArrayList` value.

Comment: main difference: there is no `add` method in `HashMap`. Second line would be like `ArrayList tmp = ans.get(key); tmp.add(s);` (would be an error if there is no list mapped to given `key`)

Answer (score 3):

`get` is getting an element from the hashmap by key, you are calling the add function on the element FROM the hashmap.

`put` is adding a new element to the hashmap.

But for the future, just read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
ans.put(key, new ArrayList());
```

This command insert a new key with a new empty ArrayList as value to the HashMap, if the key does not exists in the map, or exchange the existing key's value to the new empty ArrayList.

```
ans.get(key).add(s);
```

This command asks the HashMap for the key's value, and adds a new String value to the stored ArrayList. This command throws a NullPointerException, if key does not exists in the HashMap.

HashMap's put method stores a key-value pair.
HashMap's get method asks for a value of a key-value pair by the key.

Comment: Just a note: `key` can also be associated to `null`, in which case `get(key)` would also return `null`

Comment: `get(key)` returns null if the value is null or the key does not exists in the hashmap, returning null does not belongs to key. Hashmap also can store a null as Key, and on this situation a null key can have a not null value.